# How to get data from nodejs server to multiselect options

Tags: reactjs, axios, drop-down-menu

I'm using **react-multiple-select-dropdown-lite** and I want to set the options dynamically from my database I'm using **nodejs/mongobd**

I did this to get the data and it works

```
const [services, setServices] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:9090/user/service/getAllServices")
      .then((result) => {
        setservices(result.data);
        console.log();
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);
```

```
const [value, setvalue] = useState("");
    const handleOnchange = (val) => {
      setvalue(val);
    };
  
    const options = [
      { label: "Option 1", value: "option_1" },
      { label: "Option 2", value: "option_2" },
      { label: "Option 3", value: "option_3" },
      { label: "Option 4", value: "option_4" },

    ];
```

```
 <div className="services_selection">
   <MultiSelect onChange={handleOnchange} options={options} placeholder="Choose Services" />
 </div>
```

instead of option1 , option2 ... I want my fetched data from server. I tried many things and it didn't work

Comment: What is the definition of `setServices`? Please provide a more complete code so that we can try to look on what's happening here.

Comment: I edited the question to include the definition of **setServices**  it is `const [services, setServices] = useState([])`

Answer (score 0):

As you are fetching the options from somewhere else, you will probably want to wait for them before displaying your selector. Here is a sample of code that would work based on what you wrote.

```
const myComponent = (props: any) => {

  /**
   * I removed the empty array from the parenthesis in the useState.
   * By doing this, I tell that the default value of services is undefined.
   * This will help me later to wait for the fetch to be finished.
   */
  const [services, setServices] = useState();

  const [selectedService, setSelectedService] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:9090/user/service/getAllServices")
      .then((result) => {
        setservices(result.data);  // services will be updated from undefined to the real data only when the fetch will be finished
        setSelectedServices(result.data[0]);  // Optional, this makes sure one service will be selected by default
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  return (

    <div>Hello world</div>
    
    {/* This condition makes sure that the selector won't be displayed if services is undefined */}
    {services &&
    
      <MultiSelect 
        value={selectedService}
        onChange={(val) => setSelectedService(val)}
        options={services}
        placeholder="Choose Services"
      />
    }
  );
}
```

This is probably not exactly the code you wanted to write, but I hope it will give you clues and help you reach what you expect.

Comment: Thank you I did this : I retrieved the services from db then mapped the services into options like this  ` const options = service.map((service) => {
    return {
      label: service.name,
      value: service.id,
    };
  });
 `

and used the object options in the multiselect